# Enlarge limits by absolute value when using symbolic coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

How can I expand the x-axis by, say 1cm, in both directions in the following bar plot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,symbolic x coords={foo,bar,baz},x=2cm]
\addplot coordinates { (foo,1) (bar,3) (baz,2) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I cannot get `enlarge x limits` with `abs value` to work when using symbolic coordinates.

Using `x=2cm` to set the distance **between** the bars works fine, but how do I control the distance between the outer bars and the plot's boundary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key `abs value=bar` defines the value which *will be used if enlarge limits is active*. It will be ignored if it is not active.

Thus, activating enlarge limits will also activate the `abs value`. This can be done by means of `enlarge x limits={true,abs value=bar}`, or, equivalently, by means of `enlarge x limits={abs=bar}`.

In addition, you may want to use `xtick=data` - otherwise pgfplots tries to place tick marks between the bars and assigns them to one of the bars.

To summarize: `enlarge x limits={abs=bar}, xtick=data` does the job. It works because `bar` is the second symbolic coordinate. As such, it has index 1. Since enlargelimits necessarily needs numerical values, it uses the index of the symbolic coordinate. Thus, `abs=bar` causes the limits to be enlarged by one unit - which is 2cm in your case. Note that `foo` has index 0 and would not have worked.

This "numerics on symbols" certainly stretches the feature to its limits. If you feel that you want, say, a half unit, you should seriously consider to go back to numerical coordinates, combined with something like `xtick={0,1,2}, xticklabel=foo,bar,baz`. It has the same effect as `symbolic x coords`, although the data files are less "speaking".

Comment: This distinction between `abs value,true` and `abs=true` is certainly a bad example for a user interface, sorry about that. I admit, I did it.

Comment: I tried to use the `\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{x}{1cm}` but it's not responding. The idea that I had is that symbolic x coords still have an underlying *numerical* cs and we might be able to hack into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, something like `enlarge x limits={abs=bar}` can only increase the limits by a mutiple of `x`. Is there a way to increase the limits by, say, `0.5*bar` (i.e `1cm`)? I find a little bit unfortunate that there seems to be no way to increase limits w.r.t. to a different coordinate system than `axis cs`.

Comment: In my humble opinion, I believe that this "0.5*bar" is too much for the symbolic coordinates feature (what should that mean on its own!? Is it different from 0.5*foo ?). I understand what you want, though. If you want a different coordinate system in such cases, you may post a feature request on sourceforge. For the time being, I would suggest that you consider the solution mentioned in my last paragraph: to not use symbolic coordinates, and to place text labels manually. This allows numerical input.

Answer (score 3):

You can give `enlarge x limits` argument with a number between zero and one as a percentage. But also this would make the ticks repeat itself. To avoid that you also can give `xtick=data` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlarge x limits=0.3,xtick=data,ybar,symbolic x coords={foo,bar,baz},x=2cm]
\addplot coordinates { (foo,1) (bar,3) (baz,2) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, maybe I should have been clearer: relative distances (your `enlarge x limits=0.3`) won't work for me; I need absolute distances. Suppose I have a second bar plot with just the `foo` and `bar` bars; this plot's width would thus be smaller than the three-bar plot's. And while the distance between bars stays the same in both plots, the distance to the boundary doesn't, as it is computed relative to `xmax` - `xmin`. This is ugly.