# Broken text on bottom of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am using code below to create a graph.  On the bottom there are two braces denoted $t_1$ and $t_2$.  However numbers 1 and 2 are broken (lower part is not displayed).  What is wrong with my code?  I also tried to solve this problem using `\pgfplotsextra` to no awail.

Also, related to the code below, I would like to put into `.style` that all graphs have limit enlarged by *fixed distance*, i.e. **1 cm**.  If I understand the question [Enlarge limits by absolute value when using symbolic coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/enlarge-limits-by-absolute-value-when-using-symbolic-coordinates) right, this is not possible at all?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a7paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{standard/.style={axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=east}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,width=8cm,height=5cm,enlarge x limits=0.11,enlarge y limits=0.19,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$v$,xtick={20,60},xticklabels={,},ytick={25},yticklabels={$v'$}]

\addplot[thick,color=black] coordinates { (0,0) (20,25) (60,25) };
\addplot[dashed,very thin,color=black] coordinates { (20,0) (20,25) (0,25) };
\addplot[dashed,very thin,color=black] coordinates { (60,0) (60,25) };

\node at (axis cs:13.3,8.3) {$s_1$};
\node at (axis cs:40,12.5) {$s_2$};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:20,0) node [midway,below=1pt] {$t_1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}] (axis cs:20,0) -- (axis cs:60,0) node [midway,below=1pt] {$t_2$};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, and when I compile your code, the subscript 1 and 2 below the x axis look fine. Could you include a larger screenshot?

Comment: I can see the problem. And if I remove the `axis x line=middle` in the standard style a line appears which goes throught the bottom of the 2. With `enlarge y limits=0.22` (a larger value) this line moves down and your problem disappears.

Comment: @Jake I don't know how to do it.  Publishing latex pictures on stackexchange is horrible pain in the ass, I always have problems with that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am aware of that patch, but I do not want to extend limits.  Even now they are too extended.

Comment: @Pygmalion: Ah, I could see it at different zoom levels.

Comment: @Pygmalion: It wasn't meant as a patch but as a hint (e.g. for Jack who knows more about pgfplots) where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text gets clipped at the edge of the axis area. To prevent this, you can either provide the key `clip=false` to the `axis` options, or put the `\draw` commands in the `after end axis/.code={...}` to draw the annotations outside the clipping scope:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a7paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{standard/.style={axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=east}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    standard,
    width=8cm,height=5cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.11,enlarge y limits=0.19,
    xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$v$,
    xtick={20,60},xticklabels={,},
    ytick={25},yticklabels={$v'$},
    after end axis/.code={
        \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:20,0) node [midway,below=1pt] {$t_1$};
        \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}] (axis cs:20,0) -- (axis cs:60,0) node [midway,below=1pt] {$t_2$};
    }
]

\addplot[thick,color=black] coordinates { (0,0) (20,25) (60,25) };
\addplot[dashed,very thin,color=black] coordinates { (20,0) (20,25) (0,25) };
\addplot[dashed,very thin,color=black] coordinates { (60,0) (60,25) };

\node at (axis cs:13.3,8.3) {$s_1$};
\node at (axis cs:40,12.5) {$s_2$};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like clip=false better, because I hate options that are half a page long.  If there is no drawbacks, I stick to that.

Comment: BTW, is there any way to put enlarge axis limits in cm, possibly in \pgfplotsset{standard/.style={...?

Comment: @Pygmalion: There are drawbacks. If you're plotting data that extends beyond the `xmin` and `xmax` limits, the graph won't be clipped if you set `clip=false`. I'd go with the `after end axis/.code`. If you don't want to supply such a long option in the `axis` options, you can also just call `\pgfplotsset{after end axis/.code={
 \draw ...
    }
}` at the place where you now have your `\draw` commands.

Comment: @Pygmalion: I'd suggest opening a new question for that.

Comment: I'll do that later.  I feel so embarrased by opening dozens of questions on pgfplot only.  Seems that I am so confused about that package...