# pgfplots ybar glued to the y axis

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

My ybars are glued to my yaxis. How can I increase the horizontal space between the axis and the first bar, making them more condensed? I already tried setting x = 5cm for instance, but I just want them closer together.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fullpage, 12pt, a4paper, doublespacing]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{transfertoserver}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{database}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{transfertoclient}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{rendering}{HTML}{2B83BA}


\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  ybar=8pt,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
%          enlargelimits=0.25,
% bar width=12pt,
%  x=6cm,
ylabel={Number of Instances},
      ymin=0,
%       legend pos= outer north east,
 symbolic x coords={training set, test set},
 xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
 ]
 \addplot[fill=transfertoclient] coordinates {(test set, 35) (training set, 218)};\addlegendentry{Hits}
 \addplot[fill=rendering] coordinates {(test set, 5) (training set, 142)};\addlegendentry{Non-hits}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Class distribution of the split training and test sets.}
\label{fig:bal2}
\end{figure}
\end{document
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this option to your axis: `enlarge x limits=0.5` and play with the value to have the effect that you want. See also [Enlarge limits by absolute value when using symbolic coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/enlarge-limits-by-absolute-value-when-using-symbolic-coordinates)

```
\documentclass[fullpage, 12pt, a4paper, doublespacing]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{transfertoserver}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{database}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{transfertoclient}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{rendering}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar=8pt,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
      enlarge x limits=0.7,
      ylabel={Number of Instances},
      ymin=0,
      symbolic x coords={training set, test set},
      xtick=data,
      nodes near coords,
    ]
    \addplot[fill=transfertoclient] coordinates {(test set, 35) (training set, 218)};\addlegendentry{Hits}
    \addplot[fill=rendering] coordinates {(test set, 5) (training set, 142)};\addlegendentry{Non-hits}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]