# How to make a pgfplots barplot not fuse with the y-axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I am making a barplot like below:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={$p$[A]=0.137, $p$[N]=0.488},
                  xtick=data,
                  axis x line*=bottom,
                  axis y line=left,
                  enlarge x limits={abs=bar},
                  yticklabels={,,},
                  ylabel=p-value,
                  x=3.5 cm,
                  ymin = 0,
                  ymax = 0.55,
                  bar width=0.7cm,
                  tick style={draw=none} ]
        \addplot[ybar, black,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
            ($p$[A]=0.137, 0.137)
            ($p$[N]=0.488, 0.488)
        };

        \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:Plain,0.5);
        \coordinate (Alegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.48);
        \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:Plain,0.14);
        \coordinate (Blegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.160);
        \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:Plain,0.13);
        \coordinate (Clegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.110);
        \coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
        \coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
        \coordinate (O3) at (rel axis cs:0.5,0);

        \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
        \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);
        \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (C -| O1) -- (C -| O2);
        \node[] at (Alegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.50};
        \node[] at (Blegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.86};
        \node[] at (Clegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.87};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I would like some space between the y axis and the the first bar. Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64421/298 I though `enlarge x limits={abs=bar},` would work but it does nothing... :/

[image]

---

EDIT:

I left Overleaf which seems to just swallow some errors and here is a bit of code that runs outside of Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,12pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{red}\arabic{footnote}}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={$p$[A]=0.137, $p$[N]=0.488},
                      xtick=data,
                      axis x line*=bottom,
                      axis y line=left,
                      %enlarge x limits={true,abs value=bar},
                      ytick = {0.15, 0.30, 0.45},
                      yticklabels={0.15,0.30,0.45},
                      ylabel=p-value,
                      x=3.5 cm,
                      ymin = 0,
                      ymax = 0.55,
                      bar width=0.7cm,
                      xtick style={draw=none} ]

            \addplot[ybar, black,fill=red!30!white] coordinates {
                ($p$[A]=0.137, 0.137)
                ($p$[N]=0.488, 0.488)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is also a link to an overleaf page: https://www.overleaf.com/read/nnjqjbnvdrct

Comment: Your code is not compileable.

Comment: As @AndréC says, your code is not compilable, and it stays like this even if one adds a standard preamble since `bar` and `Plain` are not defined. And did you try to adjust `xmin`?

Comment: Hm I did this with Overleaf and now realise that it seems to have eated some of the error messages. :/ @marmot I don't think that is possible when using `symbolic x coords`

Comment: Even with XeLaTeX, the edited code is still not compileable. Maybe you can share your document on overleaf?

Comment: Oh actually I ran it on lualatex... sry about that. That was perhaps a bit unclear... 
I got the feeling that overleaf was only private things. Gonna see if I can share things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed most of the irrelevant styles and just added `enlarge x limits=0.2` to get

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,12pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{letltxmacro}
% \usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
% \usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
% \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{enumitem}
% \usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{red}\arabic{footnote}}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={$p$[A]=0.137, $p$[N]=0.488},
                      xtick=data,
                      axis x line*=bottom,
                      axis y line=left,
                      enlarge x limits=0.2,
                      %enlarge x limits={true,abs value=bar},
                      ytick = {0.15, 0.30, 0.45},
                      yticklabels={0.15,0.30,0.45},
                      ylabel=p-value,
                      %xmin=-0.2,
                      x=3.5 cm,
                      ymin = 0,
                      ymax = 0.55,
                      bar width=0.7cm,
                      xtick style={draw=none} ]

            \addplot[ybar, black,fill=red!30!white] coordinates {
                ($p$[A]=0.137, 0.137)
                ($p$[N]=0.488, 0.488)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yea that works... =)
I got stuck on all that `true, abs value=` stuff...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution given by @marmot, the pgfplots v1.16 manual specifies that this problem comes from the key `symbolic x coords={}`.

I quote the manual 1.16 page 385:

> **Symbolic coords** are useful since they reduce the burden to map strings
>   to indices and vice versa.
>
> However, they have a caveat: what if you want to set `xmin` to something to the left of the first `symbolic x coord?`
>
> This is impossible since any input coordinate is expected to be contained in `symbolic x coord`. To allow such modifications nevertheless, pgfplots checks for the magic prefix `[normalized]`:
>
> Whenever pgfplots finds a **symbolic coordinate** which starts with the precise string `[normalized]`, it will interpret everything after the prefix to be a normalized number and no symbol. In our example, `xmin` will be set to -1:7, i.e. something to the left of a (which would be 0 according to the definition above).

So I added this code: `xmin={{[normalized]-0.2},`and everything works!

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,12pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{red}\arabic{footnote}}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={$p$[A]=0.137, $p$[N]=0.488},
                      xtick=data,
                      axis x line*=bottom,
                      axis y line=left,
                      ytick = {0.15, 0.30, 0.45},
                      yticklabels={0.15,0.30,0.45},
                      ylabel=p-value,
                      xmin={[normalized]-0.2},
                      x=3.5 cm,
                      ymin = 0,
                      ymax = 0.55,
                      bar width=0.7cm,
                      xtick style={draw=none} ]

            \addplot[ybar, black,fill=red!30!white] coordinates {
                ($p$[A]=0.137, 0.137)
                ($p$[N]=0.488, 0.488)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: overleaf]