# Tikz gives errors but produces what I want, how to get rid of errors?

Tags: pgfplots

consider this code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), scale=0.85]
        \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={$p$[\texttt{A}]=0.137, $p$[\texttt{N}]=0.488},
                      xtick=data,
                      axis x line*=bottom,
                      axis y line=left,
                      enlarge x limits=0.2,
                      ytick = {0.15, 0.30, 0.45},
                      yticklabels={0.15,0.30,0.45},
                      ylabel=$p$-value,
                      x=3.5 cm,
                      ymin = 0,
                      ymax = 0.55,
                      bar width=0.7cm,
                      xtick style={draw=none} ]
            \addplot[ybar, black,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
                ($p$[\texttt{A}]=0.137, 0.137)
                ($p$[\texttt{N}]=0.488, 0.488)
            };

            \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:Plain,0.5);
            \coordinate (Alegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.48);
            \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:Plain,0.14);
            \coordinate (Blegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.160);
            \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:Plain,0.13);
            \coordinate (Clegend) at (axis cs:Plain,0.110);
            \coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
            \coordinate (O3) at (rel axis cs:0.5,0);

            \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
            \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);
            \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (C -| O1) -- (C -| O2);
            \node[] at (Alegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.50};
            \node[] at (Blegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.86};
            \node[] at (Clegend -| O3) {\color{red}\footnotesize confidence=0.87};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it I get a lot of errors like this:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `Plain' has not been defi
ned with 'symbolic x coords={$p$[\texttt {A}]=0.137, $p$[\texttt {N}]=0.488}...
 Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]Plain
?.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.44         \end{axis}

?
```

However, if I just hit `Enter` and move on it will in the end produce this plot:
[image]
Which is exactly the look I want. But how do I get it without getting the error messages? That I can't figure out.

This question is related to: [How to make a pgfplots barplot not fuse with the y-axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457880/how-to-make-a-pgfplots-barplot-not-fuse-with-the-y-axisHi), so the explanation for this behaviour is that I originally made it using Overleaf and it just swallows all eror messages as you might know... :/

Comment: What do expect `  \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:Plain,0.5);` to do? Which coordinate should this be?

Comment: Hm been a while since I did this, but I think the place where the first red dashed line intersects the y axis.

Comment: If one adds `Plain` to the `symbolic x coords` it compiles, perhaps you once had such a value.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That sounds promising but I don't understand what you mean. Can you show?

Comment: The error message says that PGFPlots doesn't know the coordinate `Plain`. And when you search your code you will find the first occurance of that in `\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:Plain,0.5);` which already **uses** this coordinate instead of defining it. That is why Ulrike suggested to add it to the symbolic coords like in `symbolic x coords={$p$[\texttt{A}]=0.137,Plain,$p$[\texttt{N}]=0.488,},`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Aha, yea that makes it compile but changes the look of the plot. I guess because I now have added a third thing on the X axis between the other two ones....

Comment: But if I instead put it first or last it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written in the comments below the question the `Plain` is causing the trouble. Here I present a solution that doesn't rely on `symbolic coords` at all and should be much easier to understand. Also I heavily simplified drawing the horizontal lines.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}
    % define a command for drawing the horizontal lines
    % optional argument: add options to the node
    % 1st mandatory argument: y-value of the horizontal line
    % 2nd mandatory argument: confidence number
    \NewDocumentCommand\HLine{O{}mm}{
        \draw [red,dashed]
            ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,#2}) --
                node [font=\footnotesize,below,#1] {confidence=#3}
            ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,#2});
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % only show ticks at x values that are used ...
        xtick=data,
        % ... and assign these labels to them
        xticklabels={
            $p$[\texttt{A}]=0.137,
            $p$[\texttt{N}]=0.488,
        },
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ytick={0.15, 0.30, 0.45},
        ylabel=$p$-value,
        x=3.5cm,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=0.55,
        bar width=0.7cm,
        xtick style={draw=none},
    ]
        \addplot[ybar, black,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
            % replaced the symbolic coords with numbers
            (0, 0.137)
            (1, 0.488)
        };

        % use the above definition to add the horizontal lines
        \HLine{0.50}{0.50}
        \HLine[above]{0.14}{0.86}
        \HLine{0.13}{0.87}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]